# how to change order script tag in head - joomla?

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, joomla3.0

I use bt-content-showcase plugin in my joomla site, slider not work but when i login it works correctly.
problem is ordering script tag in head section, how to change order script tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have some posible solutions:

Go to your extension folder, find the script link and comment this line, some extensions
 include the link in the file *helper.php*.

**A.** Manually, add this script link before `</head>` in your template.

**B.** Some templates have this option in **Extensions** > **Templates** > **Your Template**.

**C.** Using some extension like ***ScriptsDown*** or ***Javascript Async and Defer***, 
find this
 and other extensions in the [Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/core-enhancements/performance).

Regards.